# Anyone find that UIDatePicker is not showing under iOS 14?

Tags: swift

I am trying to display date picker on button click. In iOS 13 that is working fine but when run on iOS 14 it is not showing.

Comment: Could you show you tried code?

Comment: Please don't make edits that ask a whole different question, invalidating existing answers. Ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Go on your Storyboard and click on your calendar after go to Preferred Style attribute and change from `Automatic` (default value set by iOS 14) to `Wheels`. Now your calendar will show up again.

[image]